# How to merge 2 queries into my while loop in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to only show posts of type "offered" or "wanted" but I want all the original wordpress query object returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about something like

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => array( 'offered', 'wanted'), 
                              'post_status' => 'published',
                              'posts_per_page' => 10
                            ) 
                     );
```

this should only show posts where the post type is either offered OR wanted, that is published and list 10 per page.

then just use the loop

```
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
       the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```